# Using non-negative derivative to enforce same results between functions

Tags: derivative, q-learning

I have been reading the paper [QMIX: Monotonic value function factorisation for deep multi-agent reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11485) to understand some concepts about Q-function factorisation. There is this part that reads: [see image]
[Q function constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl8al.png)
I have been searching online, without success, to understand how this constraint ensures that the result of Q_tot is equal to the set of `argmax` of each Q_a.

Can anyone help me understand the intuition here?

I searched online to find resources that provide some insights but nothing yet.